# Same variable declared twice. Which is one used? -- JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

The code below will produce `8` due to the fact the second declaration will override the first one. Yup! Makes total sense.

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
function foo(){
    function bar() {
        return 3;
    }
    return bar();
    function bar() {
        return 8;
    }
}
console.log(foo()); // ---> 8
```

The following code produces `3` which means that it is the first expression that is invoked.

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
function foo(){
    var bar = function() {
        return 3;
    };
    return bar();
    var bar = function() {
        return 8;
    };
}
console.log(foo()); // ---> 3
```

I tend to conclude that in JavaScript, only the first declared variable is used as shown above. However, the code below produces `7` (hmmm... scratching my head)

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
var a = 4;
var a = 7;
console.log(a); //---> 7
```

Eventually, I will be using `let` or `const` (to prevent declaring the same variable many times) to declare variables and not `var` but I'm trying to understand why the results produced in example 2 and 3 are so unpredictable. Thanks.

Comment: There's only one variable (declarations are hoisted), but assignments (initialisations) happen in order.

Comment: Why does let a=1; let a =1 gives error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Example 1* is equivalent to the below code. Here `bar` is overridden before the `return`, so it is evaluated with the last value which is assigned to it. More about you can read [**Variable and Function Hoisting**](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-variable-hoisting-differentiating-between-var-let-and-const-in-es6-f1a70bb43d).

```js
function foo(){
    function bar() {
        return 3;
    }
    
    function bar() {
        return 8;
    }
    
    return bar(); 
}
console.log(foo());
```

*Example 2* is equivalent to the below code. Here you can see that `bar` is declared only once and the first value is assigned to it. The second assignment is done after the return, so the code does not reach to it. And the `return` is executed with the first assignment.

```js
function foo(){
    var bar;
    bar = function() {
        return 3;
    };
    
    return bar();
    
    bar = function() {
        return 8;
    };
}
console.log(foo());
```

What about *Example 3*, when you declare the same variable many times with `var`, the later `var`s are just ignored. So like this

```js
var a = 4;
a = 7;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it's just a difference how you declare the functions.

It's exactly the difference between `var functionName = function() {}` and `function functionName() {}`

Consider you have two functions.

```
var function1 = function() {

};
function function2() {

}
```

The difference is that `function1` is a function expression and so only defined when that line is reached.

```
function1();
var function1 = function() {

};
```

When the compiler reaches this line will throw an error like `function1` is not defined.

`function2` is a function declaration and it's globally (due to **hoisting**).

```
function2();
function function2() {

}
```

This code will invoke the `function2` function.

So, in your first example it's same like `function2` (there is a function declaration).

In your second example it's same like `function1` (there is a function expression)